# deformer does not work for my mdoel in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added mesh collider,rigidbody as well as the deform script to the 3d model I imported from 3dsmax, but when plays scene, my model does not deforms. I tried to create an gameObject to be the parent of my 3d asset, in this case the model will just fall off and not have any contact with any objects, so I have no idea on what to do to fix this.

this is the deform script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Deform : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float deformRadius = 0.2f;
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float maxDeform = 0.1f;
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float damageFalloff = 1;
    [Range(0, 10)]
    public float damageMultiplier = 1;
    [Range(0, 100000)]
    public float minDamage = 1;

    public AudioClip[] collisionSounds;

    private MeshFilter filter;
    private Rigidbody physics;
    private MeshCollider coll;
    private Vector3[] startingVerticies;
    private Vector3[] meshVerticies;

    void Start()
    {
        filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        physics = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        if (GetComponent<MeshCollider>())
            coll = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();

        startingVerticies = filter.mesh.vertices;
        meshVerticies = filter.mesh.vertices;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        float collisionPower = collision.impulse.magnitude;

        if (collisionPower > minDamage)
        {
            if (collisionSounds.Length > 0)
                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(collisionSounds[Random.Range(0, collisionSounds.Length)], transform.position, 0.5f);

            foreach (ContactPoint point in collision.contacts)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < meshVerticies.Length; i++)
                {
                    Vector3 vertexPosition = meshVerticies[i];
                    Vector3 pointPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(point.point);
                    float distanceFromCollision = Vector3.Distance(vertexPosition, pointPosition);
                    float distanceFromOriginal = Vector3.Distance(startingVerticies[i], vertexPosition);

                    if (distanceFromCollision < deformRadius && distanceFromOriginal < maxDeform) // If within collision radius and within max deform
                    {
                        float falloff = 1 - (distanceFromCollision / deformRadius) * damageFalloff;

                        float xDeform = pointPosition.x * falloff;
                        float yDeform = pointPosition.y * falloff;
                        float zDeform = pointPosition.z * falloff;

                        xDeform = Mathf.Clamp(xDeform, 0, maxDeform);
                        yDeform = Mathf.Clamp(yDeform, 0, maxDeform);
                        zDeform = Mathf.Clamp(zDeform, 0, maxDeform);

                        Vector3 deform = new Vector3(xDeform, yDeform, zDeform);
                        meshVerticies[i] -= deform * damageMultiplier;
                    }
                }
            }

            UpdateMeshVerticies();
        }
    }

    void UpdateMeshVerticies()
    {
        filter.mesh.vertices = meshVerticies;
        coll.sharedMesh = filter.mesh;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: yoshiro, please edit your question with adding text formated error message

Answer (score 0):

Any time you modify the vertices of a mesh you have to tell the game that it should re-calculate them.

The way you can do that is instead of setting the vertices using `filter.mesh.vertices` [instead use `filter.mesh.SetVertices(meshVerticies);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetVertices.html) and just to be sure you can tell the engine it should check all the other things about the mesh to make sure they make sense.

Update you `UpdateMeshVerticies()` to something like this, and it should work a treat.

```cs
void UpdateMeshVerticies()
{
    filter.mesh.SetVertices(meshVerticies);

    filter.mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    filter.mesh.RecalculateTangents();
    filter.mesh.RecalculateBounds();

    if (coll != null)
    {
        coll.sharedMesh = filter.mesh;
    }
}
```